# How to express the list inside the list with Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently I have the following data.

```
data class A(val b: List<B>? = null, val id: String, val title: String)

data class B(val name: String, val price: String)
```

The data response by the server is `List<A>`, the RecyclerView should show the name and price of b and when I click on the RecyclerView the id value of A should be passed to the next activity.

How to solve it using RecyclerView inside RecyclerView and how to do View Add in RecylcerView might be the solution, but I would like to know best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating vertical RecyclerView of A with dynamic amount of vertical RecyclerViews of B, then I would create one RecyclerView with flatten list of A and B and do something like this:

```kotlin
sealed class RecyclerItem {

    data class ItemA(val id: String, val title: String): RecyclerItem()
    
    data class ItemB(val name: String, val price: String): RecyclerItem()

}
```

```kotlin
class YourAdapter(private val recyclerItems: List<RecyclerItem>, private val onItemAClickListener: (Int) -> Unit) : ReycyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val TYPE_A = 0
private val TYPE_B = 1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return when(viewType) {
        TYPE_A -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_a, parent, false).apply {
            it.setOnClickListener {
                onItemAClickListener((recyclerItems[position] as RecyclerItem.ItemA).id)
        }
        TYPE_B -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_b, parent, false)
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = return when(recyclerItems[position]) {
    is RecyclerItem.ItemA -> TYPE_A
    is RecyclerItem.ItemB -> TYPE_B
}

override fun getItemCount() = recyclerItems.size

}
```

```kotlin
data class A(val b: List<B>? = null, val id: String, val title: String)

data class B(val name: String, val price: String)

val dataResponse: List<A> // response from the server with list of A

val itemsList = arrayListOf<RecyclerItem>() // list that will contain flatten A and B

dataResponse.forEach { a ->
    itemsList.add(RecyclerItem.ItemA(a.id, a.title))
    it.b.forEach { b -> 
        itemsList.add(RecyclerItem.ItemB(b.name, b.price))
    }
}

// setup RecyclerView in your Activity/Fragment

val adapter = YourAdapter(itemsList) { idOfA -> 
 //go to next activity with id of A
}
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

If you are creating vertical RecyclerView of A with dynamic amount of horizontal RecyclerViews of B, then I would suggest this blogpost: https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: The code in the answer and the current code are very similar and the goal is to use the data received from the server without converting it. I want to use the RecyclerItem code without modifying it even if the server key field is added later.

Comment: Then pass object A and object B inside corresponding `ItemA` and `ItemB` and use them there

Comment: I asked a question to find a better solution than this, but I think this is the best. Thank you :)

Comment: Well you have to either have List<Any>, put everything there and cast or check everywhere, or create for example the sealed class like in the answer and get rid off casting